# Get Each Select Element's Selected Value and Log to Console

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function below is logging one value to console instead of 2 values. Ultimately My project will have multiple select elements and I need to pass the value of each select element through a function.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="choice">
  <select name="selecttype">
    <option value="0">choice 1</option>
    <option value="1">choice 2</option>
    <option value="" selected>N/A</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="choice">
  <select name="selecttype">
    <option value="0">choice 1</option>
    <option value="1">choice 2</option>
    <option value="" selected>N/A</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="logvalues" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">log values to console</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#logvalues").click(function() {
   $("option:selected").each(function(){
      console.log($("option:selected").val());
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the current context using `this` like:

```
$("#logvalues").click(function() {
  $("option:selected").each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).val() );
  });
})
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("#logvalues").click(function() {
  $("option:selected").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="choice">
  <select name="selecttype">
    <option value="0">choice 1</option>
    <option value="1">choice 2</option>
    <option value="" selected>N/A</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="choice">
  <select name="selecttype">
    <option value="0">choice 1</option>
    <option value="1">choice 2</option>
    <option value="" selected>N/A</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="logvalues" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">log values to console</button>
```